# Integration with hyperbolic substitution

Tags: calculus

I need to find:

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{x-a}{x+a}} ~dx$$

I want to substitute $x$ with $a*\cosh$,but I get confused ,because  $x \gt a$ or $ x \lt -a$ ,and $a*\cosh$ works only in the first case. Could you please find this integral and justify each step you make, especially the part with substitution?

Do I need to show that there is one-to-one correspondence between the domain of my variable and the range of the new function?

Comment: I apologize ,it should be x-a/x+a

Comment: Then fix it in the problem please

Comment: What are the limits of integration?

Comment: It's an indefinite integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, substitute $x=a \cosh{t}$, $dx=a \sinh{t} dt$, get

$$a\int dt \sinh{t} \tanh{(t/2)} = a\int dt\: 2 \sinh^2{(t/2)}$$

or the integral equals

$$a \int dt \: (\cosh{t}-1) = a (\sinh{t}-t)+C = a \left [ \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2}-1} - \mathrm{arccosh}{\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}\right ]+C$$

where $C$ is an integration constant.

Comment: What about the case when  x<-a ?

Comment: Then you have imaginary arguments, and the cosh's become cosines.  But in that case, you wouldn't express the integrand like that; you would have the $x$ and $a$ reversed.  So the analysis is certainly valid, but it involves imaginary numbers, that's all.

Comment: How about $x = -a\cosh t$?

Comment: It will produce a factor of $i$ and a $+ t$ instead of a $-t$.  But then substitute back and everything should work out.  Really, try this yourself.

Comment: Do you take t>0 and why?

Comment: Sure, but I don't think it matters.